# Use a query in a query, but query became null

Tags: php, mysql

So I want to select data from a table in my DB and want to use that data in a other select query, I try but my last query became a null, So what did I wrong ?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `DBovervieuw` WHERE owner =" . $owner;
$result_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)) {
    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM `card` WHERE DBid=" . $result['ID'];
    $Finale_set = mysqli_query($connection, $Finale_set);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_ASSOC($Finale_set)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

}
echo json_encode($data);
```

I will do my BIND variable later

Comment: what is the value of $owner supposed to be

Comment: Adding to jonju's comment: unless `$owner` is something like `column_name = 'some_value'`, this is not proper syntax. You can `echo $query` to check how the string turned up. **Edit:** or even better, use [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: it is a 4, so a INT, but the stmt is failing

Comment: _"I will do my BIND variable later"_. Binding would've probably prevented this mess in the first place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi the main thing here you are missing is in the second `WHERE`  ( Update .. actually both queries )

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `DBovervieuw` WHERE " . $owner;

 $stmt = "SELECT * FROM `card` WHERE " . $result['ID'];
```

You have no column name.  So where what?

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `DBovervieuw` WHERE {insert column name here } = " . $owner;
```

Think if `$owner` is an id with a value of 1 then you have this query..

```
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `DBovervieuw` WHERE 1"
```

Which will just return all the records in the table.

That said a simple Join may be preferable here, then 2 queries

```
 $query = "SELECT
               d.*, c.*
           FROM
               `DBovervieuw` AS d
           JOIN
               card AS c
           ON
               d.ID = c.DBid
           WHERE d.owner = " . $owner;
```

Without knowing those column names that's the best I can do...  Essentially instead of the second where you use that relationship as the `ON` in the join.  Then you can save yourself a bunch of query calls to the DB, and it makes the code much shorter and easier because you have all the data on hand, and can probably avoid a second ( nested ) while loop.

**UPDATE**
This is also an issue.

```
  $stmt = "SELECT * FROM `card` WHERE DBid=" . $result['ID'];
  $Finale_set = mysqli_query($connection, $Finale_set);
```

I think you want this instead:,

```
  $stmt = "SELECT * FROM `card` WHERE DBid=" . $result['ID'];
  $Finale_set = mysqli_query($connection, $stmt);  //<-----
```

By the way that is responsible for the empty query error, because you used `$Finale_set` before defining it. Which would be `NULL` as your SQL, thereby giving you the empty query error.  It's the wrong variable though, so we'll just use the correct one instead of defining it.

Cheers.

As a side note the `$stmt` variable is typically used when using `PDO` it stands for  `PDOstatement`  http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php  So convention wise I would change that simply to `$sql`.  But that is just a best practice sort of thing.

Comment: So true, Sorry i fix'd the error , it's a long day :D

Comment: @FirstOne - what if `$owner = 1`, it would indeed reach the second one,.  `SELECT * FROM DBovervieuw WHERE  1` is perfectly valid

Comment: @FirstOne - Updated, I wasn't quite finished with it.  But thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Okay i did change some things. But is still give the error Empty query on 39 ( that's the $stmt) . Okay i will try the Join query ( first time )

Comment: THANKS , is so a stupid questions. sorry is was a embarrassing

Comment: No question is stupid, if you learn something from it, Glad I could help..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have certain typo in one or two lines:

here

`$query = "SELECT * FROM DBovervieuw' WHERE " . $owner;`

And here

```
$stmt = "SELECT * FROM 'card' WHERE " . $result['ID'];
```

try something like this:

**EDITED**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM DBovervieuw WHERE owner='".$owner."'";
$result_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)) {
    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM `card` WHERE DBid=" . $result['ID'];
    $Finale_set = mysqli_query($connection, $stmt);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_ASSOC($Finale_set)) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Notice the `Owner_id` & `Card_id`. These two are the Column Name of your corresponding table base on which you want to search. You must change these two Columns with the real Column Name.

Comment: it give this : Empty query 39, (thats the $stmt)

Comment: Did you  replaced the Owner_id & Card_id with your column name?. Show  your table

Comment: is the column 'owner' string or number if it's string you need to put a single quotation after =